# Why arrays invented to be 0-based and not 1-based?

Tags: arrays

When you want to read the first elemen in an array, you always have to read it by using the number 0. this is what I know from several languages.

My question is why this is the accepted standard?
Why it was decided that the first item is represented by 0 and not 1?

When I think about it, 0 does not make sense to me. 
Because by the definition of 0, 0 is "nothing". and the "first item/data" is not "nothing". it is minimum 1. so why 0?

In my little experience in math, I constantly have to refer to 0 as one.
math itself does not seems to like this idea..

So why it is the accepted standard in programing languages?

Thank you.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm

Comment: Thank you. I see I'm certainly not the only one who thinks this way. I very much agree with what the "fellow programmer" said.. 

I see that this debate is very big.. I hope one day 0 will be 1 as should be.

Comment: simply switch to MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this Wiki article would help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering

> Martin Richards, creator of the BCPL language (a precursor of C),
>   designed arrays initiating at 0 as the natural position to start
>   accessing the array contents in the language, since the value of a
>   pointer p used as an address accesses the position p+0 in memory.